# Pytorch Resnet model error if FC layer is changed in Colab

Tags: pytorch, google-colaboratory, resnet

If I simply import the Resnet Model from Pytorch in Colab, and use it to train my dataset, there are no issues. However, when I try to change the last FC layer to change the output features from 1000 to 9, which is the number of classes for my datasets, the following error is obtained.

```
RuntimeError: Tensor for 'out' is on CPU, Tensor for argument #1 'self' is on CPU, but expected them to be on GPU (while checking arguments for addmm)
```

Working version:

```
import torchvision.models as models
#model = Net()
model=models.resnet18(pretrained=True)

# defining the optimizer
optimizer = Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.07)
# defining the loss function
criterion = CrossEntropyLoss()
# checking if GPU is available
if torch.cuda.is_available():
    model = model.cuda()
    criterion = criterion.cuda()
```

Version with error:

```
import torchvision.models as models
#model = Net()
model=models.resnet18(pretrained=True)

# defining the optimizer
optimizer = Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.07)
# defining the loss function
criterion = CrossEntropyLoss()
# checking if GPU is available
if torch.cuda.is_available():
    model = model.cuda()
    criterion = criterion.cuda()
model.fc = torch.nn.Linear(512, 9)
```

Error occurs in the stage where training occurs, aka

```
outputs = model(images)
```

How should I go about fixing this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple error, the fc layer should be instantiated before declaring model as cuda.
I.e

```
model=models.resnet18(pretrained=True)
model.fc = torch.nn.Linear(512, 9)
if torch.cuda.is_available():
    model = model.cuda()
```